# Running localstack start command taking too long to start on mac

Tags: docker, localstack

running IMAGE_NAME=localstack/localstack-full:0.12.6 localstack start on mac(arm64) but its taking too long to start. On checking the docker container found out that its pulling all localstack image of approx size 800mb.I need to explicitly download the localstack/localstack-full:0.12.6 image before it even started. Anyone knows how to fix it?

localstack version : 0.14.4
Mac: arm64

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I had the same issue when I used version 0.12.6. I have no idea why I had it. Anyway, using a recent one fixed mine.